# Menu misaligned when a submenu appears

Tags: html

Im trying to create an submenu that appears when we put our mouse over it. I did that but sadly it misaligns the others menu links when i put my mouse over.
Anyone knows how to solve this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAuSe.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXvQf.png

I would like to make other parts of the main menu to stay aligned to the "Serviços" Menu!

CSS menu code:

```
 .cssmenu {
    display: block;
 }
 .cssmenu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
 }

.cssmenu > ul > li.active a{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color: rgb(239, 127, 27);
    box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
}
.cssmenu > ul > li span img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Cagliostro', sans-serif;
    color: #555555;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    padding: 12px 28px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.active a:hover{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color: rgb(239, 127, 27);
    box-shadow: 0 8px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 0.9s;
    -moz-transition: 0.9s;
    -o-transition: 0.9s;
    transition: 0.9s;
    background-color: rgb(239, 127, 27);
    box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 6px rgb(191, 99, 14);
    color: #ffffff;
}
ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul{
    display: block; 
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="cssmenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Inicio</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html"><span>Quem Somos</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="staff.html"><span>Parceiros</span></a></li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="service.html"><span>Serviços</span></a>
            <ul> 
            <li> <a href="casamentos.html">CASAMENTOS </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="aniversarios.html">ANIVERSÁRIOS </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="batizados.html"> BATIZADOS </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="comunhoes.html"> COMUNHÕES </a> </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="last"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contactos</span></a></li>
            <div class="clear"></div>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add [this jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/WLV7r/) to your post :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mCwEp/ Here is did it for him, since i am sorting through it.

Comment: Thanks guys im new here xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer. Add `position:absolute;` to `ul li ul`.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/WLV7r/1/)

CSS

```
ul li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't XHTML compliant. You can't write the following code under the `<ul>`: `<div class="clear"></div>`

Comment: @Kyuubi96 - just remove `<div class="clear"></div>`, it is not needed.

Comment: Also, you need to add the `top:0` and the `left:0` properties in order to have a cross-browser compliant code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/WLV7r/2/

```
  .cssmenu > ul > li {float:left;}
```

You need to the float the menu items next to each other.
You also need to put the `<div class="clear"></div>` outside the `<ul>` to be XHTML compliant.

Comment: You might want to add some margin for the menu items